# MongoDB does not seem to want to push to array

Tags: php, mongodb, insert, push, shopping-cart

I am making an online shopping cart, and I having huge issues pushing add to cart to items

```
 $collection->update(
                array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"],
                array('$push'=>
                array('items'=> $_POST["item"])
                )));
```

When the customer selects their first item to add to the cart it works fine

```
   $collection->insert(
   array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"],
   'status' => "cart",
   'items' =>$_POST['item']));
```

but after the first item is added it does not allow me to add any more.

Please any advice would be helpful.

Comment: if you make it a safe update and print out the return of the function what does MongoDB say?

Comment: If you are using v1.3+ of the PHP driver just wrap a `var_dump()` around the update call and post that here otherwise if you are using pre-1.3 then add `array('safe' => true)` as the third param of the update call and `var_dump` that here too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert it the first time, the `items` field is not array (probably a string).

According to the  [mongodb $push doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) :

> The operation will fail if the field specified in the $push statement
>   is not an array.

Change your insert operation to :

```
$collection->insert(
   array(
      'session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"],
      'status' => "cart",
      'items' => array($_POST['item'])
   ));
```

Then run your update query.