# PHP updating MongoDB sub array

Tags: php, mongodb

I am wanting to update my sub-array in MongoDB
Here is what the MongoDB Collection looks like

```
    array (
      '_id' => new MongoId("510fb81638fc5d2966000000"),
      'items' => 
      array (
        '0' => 
        array (
          'id' => '510bb69538fc5d0c2d000000',
          'quantity' => '1',
        ),
        '1' => 
        array (
          'id' => '510bca8138fc5d6e38000000',
          'quantity' => '1',
        ),
      ),
      'session' => '1359964785.85203874781',
      'status' => 'cart'
)
```

I created my form to send the following

however when I try to $set it to mongo

```
$filter =  array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"]);
$data2 = array(
                '$set' => array($_POST['items'])
            );
$options = array("upsert" => true);
$collection->update( $filter, $data2, $options );
```

Nothing seems to update

Comment: Posting duplicates won't get your answer sooner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687113/mongodb-does-not-seem-to-want-to-push-to-array finish the other first

Comment: Not A duplicate question if you read that question and this question totally different as that question was inserting into a sub array this is updating the sub array - might seem same but very different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sammaye said, you've overlooked your query. And, do you want to update, replace or push to an array?

To **replace** all of items :

```
$data2 = array('$set' => array('items' => array($_POST['items'])));
$collection->update( array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"]), $data2, array("upsert" => true) );
```

To **update** the first array of items :

```
$data2 = array('$set' => array('items.0' => $_POST['items']));
$collection->update(array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"]), $data2, array("upsert" => true) );
```

And to **push** to the items array :

```
$data2 = array('$push' => array('items' => $_POST['items']));
$collection->update(array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"]), $data2, array("upsert" => true) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your set is wrong:

```
$filter =  array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"]);
$data2 = array('$set' =>array('items' => array($_POST['items'])));

$options = array("upsert" => true);
$collection->update( $filter, $data2, $options );
```

I should mention using the `$_POST` in this way is asking for some one to hack your shopping site.

Comment: +1 for the remark on the ***slight*** lack of security in this approach